# Trouble removing old wide-spread faucet

Tags: faucet

I'm having several issues removing an old widespread faucet from my sink and could use a hand in naming a few pieces and trying to determine if I can remove this thing with existing tools or will i have to cut it out with a rotary tool.

Lets look at some pics shall we, top half of the photo is the faucet with the pfister marquis styled handle covers removed.

Bottom left of image is of stem underneath handle, I can't unscrew that rounded, bronze colored cap, have sprayed copious amounts of WD40 on there, not sure if loosening that nut will allow access to area that can help in removing handle from topside.

Bottom right of image is of down stem and brass fittings from underneath.  The basin nut is something I have never seen or heard of, can't find n image of it online.  Would be nice if someone could point me to the name of that thin threaded nut with the square notches in it:

Even if I had a tool to loose that nut (basin wrench will not grab ahold of it due to its slim profile), how would I remove that brass tee fitting there?  It doesn't look like that tee is section is attached to anything, looks like all one piece.   when I used the basin wrench the tee fitting, the whole thing spun around together. So I'm officially confused and a bit frustrated after looking at this situation for 3 hours.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Our house is from 1970 and we have three of the exact same model faucets. The handle in particular is a bit rough on the hands so we were eager to replace. The drain cover says Price-Pfister.

Similar to above, the spanner nut was in there tight. On one of the replacements, I was able to use a type of hook wrench pictured to function as a way to hold it in place while I turned the underside of the spigot clockwise. This caused it to loosen. On another, I had to spray some WD40 on there to loosen it then once again hold it in place while I turned the underside of the spigot clockwise.

On both there was no budging the top assembly. Essentially you have to loosen it enough to be able to pull and expose enough spigot to take a mini hacksaw and saw it a little more than halfway. It takes about 10 minutes. After that it bends and breaks rather easily. Fortunately I did not need to break out the Dremel tool.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 1):

That's a **spanner nut**. For which you need a **hook spanner wrench**.

[image]

([source](http://www.thisoldtractor.com/dr350_shock_adjustment_wrench.html))

Or you could try a **basin wrench** again, with someone else's help turning, as you'll need both hands to keep it in place and resist their torque.

[image]

([source](http://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/74779901))

Comment: Spanner nut...thanks alot for that, I will be able to do some research and make sure I get the proper hook spanner wrench for the job...

Answer (score -2):

6 step faucet seat wrench removal tool.. about 8 bucks at home depot

Comment: A picture would help. Are you talking about the kind that looks like an [Allen key or a giant fork](https://www.google.com/search?q=6+step+faucet+seat+wrench&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6-tiOp7nQAhVrxYMKHZ5lCMgQ_AUICSgC&biw=1024&bih=639)?

Comment: I saw some spanner wrenches at lowes today, but they are way too big for what I was needing.  That spanner nut is only 1/2 inch opening...

Comment: yes,, the kind that looks like the allen wrench,,but the end has steps...

Comment: also,,, MAKE SURE YOU TURN OFF THE WATER SUPPLY BEFORE YOU START REMOVING THE VALVE STEMS..

Comment: I ended up cutting the spammer nuts off with a small hacksaw...the local hardware stores didn't carry spammer wrenches in the size I neeedes and I needed to get the job done...I cut them and broke them off.